# How to access gradle's --test property in build.gradle.kts

Tags: kotlin, gradle, gradle-kotlin-dsl

When I execute a single test with gradle I can use `--tests` option. I now want to access this property inside `build.gradle.kts` in order to detect if only a single test is run.

If i run `./gradlew test --tests com.example.MyTest`, I want to have the string value of `com.example.MyTest`

Unfortunately I do not find any way (I already searched project and system properties).

Answer (score 0):

After hours of debugging I found a solution inside:

`project.gradle.startParameter.taskRequests[0].args`

Be careful since the args array is filled differently by your IDE and the `gradlew` CLI

If you start gradle with the CLI like in my question `./gradlew test --tests com.example.MyTest` the array will have the values

`["test", "--tests", "com.example.MyTest"]`